# How do you put text on a pygame screen?

Tags: python, text, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I am making a game and I want there to be a score at the top left. How would I put text up there and can I make it a variable? I have tried looking online but everything I've seen is way too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
text = font.render('Text', BackGround(T or F), ForeColor (or Font Colour), Background Color)
```